# Mongoose rename _id to id on child docs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got this Mongoose model schema containing 'hardcoded' child docs
and I can't figure out how I can rename the _id into id for the child docs.

For the parent I use the following code to include the id prop as well, but this doesn't seem to work for the child docs.

```
menuItemSchema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true
})
```

What I tried:

```
menuItemSchema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true,
  extras: {    // <-- child
    virtuals: true,
  }
})
```

**Schema**

```
const menuItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  extras: [{   // <-- child
    name: {
      type: String
    },
    ...otherProps
  }],
  ...otherProps
})

menuItemSchema.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true
})
```

Is there a way? Do I need to create a separated schema just to enable

```
.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true })
```

**Result**

```
{
  "_id": "5b2691666034483916a59fe8",
  "name": "Margharita",
  "extras": [
    {
      "_id": "5b2691666034483916a59fed",
      "name": "Sauce"
      // ^ got no id
    }, 
    ...
  ],
  "__v": 0,
  "id": "5b2691666034483916a59fe8"  // <- got id
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toJSON`/`toObject` does not accept option `extras`, it will do nothing on the schema. [Reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Mongoose document will have an `id` virtual getter by default. [Refercence](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id)

Try to define the child schema explicitly:

```
const ExtraSchema = new Schema({...});

const menuItemSchema = new Schema({
  extras : [ExtraSchema]
});
```

If this doesn't work, try the `transform` option in `toJSON`:

```
ExtraSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform : (doc, result) => {
    return {
      ...result,
      id : result._id
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: so as far as u know there is no way to do it without defining a separated schema?

Comment: If you do not care about the values, you can define an `id` property directly in the child schema within the parent schema, then your `extra` will have two different values for `_id` and `id`. Otherwise, defining a separated schema could give you more control on it.